# iOS7 Xcode 5 Upgrade makes longpress crash app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have an app that I've been working on, which worked perfectly a few hours ago. I downloaded DP5 of Xcode-5, upgraded my storyboards using the built in upgrade storyboard features.

When I launch the app it works. It's a basic map app. I have an action for to register a longpress, and then drop a pin annotation on the map and now the app crashes without any error, except showing the line in the compiler code where it fails: `0x102d49c:  calll  0x102d4a1                 ; -[NSPathStore2 isEqualToString:] + 17` and a cryptic message of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting. I'm downloading the release build of Xcode 5 right now to see if that fixes it.

--Update--

I've also tried a clean build, restarting the simulator and Xcode.

I used breakpoints and it seems that the app is having trouble specifically with adding the annotation to the map `[self.mapView addAnnotation:annot];`

Comment: Sounds like it's time to start hunting for [zombies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html).

Comment: @BergQuester ugh. Will do. Any idea why it would happen from upgrading though? Thanks!

Comment: There's probably a change in the system frameworks with the jump form iOS 6 to iOS 7. I remember when 10.8 came out we found a memory issue in our OS X app. (a static autoreleased object) Looking at the code it should have never worked. We had gotten lucky (probably because something in the frameworks was retaining the object) until something changed in the OS changed with the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woot! Solved the issue. Hope this helps someone.

I was using [Apple's stock code for annotating maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW47).

When I built the app for iOS6, by default, adding a pin annotation did NOT show the disclosure right away.

So I added this line of code to select the annotation and display my annotation by default. Removing this line fixed it, and in iOS7, the disclosure shows by default anyway!
        `[mapView selectAnnotation:pinView.annotation animated:YES];`